# Unable to select RADIO BUTTON from excel input using VBA CODE

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel I have drop down on C41 cell. If C41 cell has "prime-membership" than "prime-membership" radio button should be selected on the web page and if C41 has "non-prime-membership" than "non-prime-membership" radio button should be selected on the web page. Here is the code I have framed and this is not working.

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C41").Value = "prime-membership" Then
    With IE.Document

    .getElementById("prime-membership").Click
    
End With
End If

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C41").Value = "non-prime-membership" Then
    With IE.Document

    .getElementById("non-prime-membership").Click
    
End With
```

Here is inspect element for "prime-membership" and "non-prime-membership".

```
<div data-a-input-name="membershipRadio" class="a-radio a-radio-fancy"><label for="prime-membership"><input id="prime-membership" type="radio" name="membershipRadio" value="true" checked=""><i class="a-icon a-icon-radio"></i><span class="a-label a-radio-label">Prime Members</span></label></div>

<div data-a-input-name="membershipRadio" class="a-radio a-radio-fancy"><label for="non-prime-membership"><input id="non-prime-membership" type="radio" name="membershipRadio" value="false"><i class="a-icon a-icon-radio"></i><span class="a-label a-radio-label">Non-Prime Members</span></label></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons don't have a click event. Try this:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C41").Value = "prime-membership" Then
  IE.Document.getElementById("prime-membership").Checked = True
Else
  IE.Document.getElementById("non-prime-membership").Checked = True
End If
```

Comment: The core of my answer is `"Radio buttons do not have a click event"`. You should be able to do your own research with that.